the simplification of Matrix-by-Matrix derivative
I was reading the Details of the exact derivative computations section of a paper and came across the following process:

As a result, we opted for a more intuitive, yet equivalently expressive representation for optimization. The covariance matrix $\Sigma$
of a 3D Gaussian is analogous to describing the configuration of an
ellipsoid. Given a scaling matrix  and rotation matrix $R$, we can
find the corresponding $\Sigma$:
$$
\Sigma=RSS^TR^T
$$
......
Since Σ = $RSS^TR^T$,
we can compute $M$=$RS$ and rewrite $\Sigma=MM^T$.
......  
Since the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ (and its gradient) is symmetric, the shared first part is compactly found by $\frac{d\Sigma}{dM}=2M^T$

I know the Matrix-by-matrix derivative formula uses the Kronecker product, but I don't understand how it can be varied to such a brief result (I can't even simplify $\otimes$).
Are the ones here using some definitions I'm not aware of? How should I interpret this result?
I apologize if I have used inappropriate words, Is there anyone who can teach me? Thanks.

If the paper is from a reputable journal, I can only assume that you've misstated the result, and it actually says something like
$$\frac{\partial\operatorname{trace}(\Sigma) }{\partial M} = 2M^T$$

This paper is from SIGGRAPH 2023 on 3DGS (3D Gaussian Splatting for Real-Time Radiance Field).
My quote from the article in question was formula (6) and (9).
So they're using $\frac{d\Sigma}{dM}=2M^T$ directly to abbreviate $\frac{\partial{trace(\Sigma)}}{\partial{M}}=2M^T$?
